# How to display label and field output inline

Tags: views, theming, forms

I want to display same line label and fields in drupal 8. But by default it's showing field down and label up.

I'm using suffix and prefix it works. 
How can I display it without suffix and prefix?

```
 $form['doc_date'] = array(
'#type' => 'date',
'#required' => TRUE,
'#date_date_format' => 'd-m-Y', 
'#default_value' => (isset($record['doc_date']) && $_GET['num']) ? $d_date:'',
  '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-180 days', 'max' => date('d-m-Y') ),
  '#prefix' => '<tr><td><table><tr><td class="tdtext_form_cre">Document Date : <span class="mand">*</span><td>',
'#suffix' => '</td></tr></table></td></tr>',
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to default field.html.twig file template which is use to render fields, you have to set `#label_display => 'inline'`
and `#title => 'Your label'`
Most of themes render inline label and content when class field--label-inline exist, but it is possible that you remove this css style from your theme.

Comment: Thanks, I have solve this issues using the table concept **field.html.twig**  making complex for other field .

Answer (score 0):

In the views page, field settings, style settings change HTML element to `span`.[image]